# Angular typescript and Ngrx Store interface, how access correct interface property?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, properties, ngrx-store

I just watched a tutorial and was a bit confused:
There was an interface for a submit for to register a user:

```
export interface RegisterRequestInterface {
  user: {
    email: string,
    password: string,
    username: string,
  },
}
```

and for Ngrx Store in the actions.ts:

```
export interface RegisterRequestInterface {
  user: {
    email: string,
    password: string,
    username: string,
  },
}

export const registerAction = createAction(
 ActionTypes.REGISTER,
  props<{ request: RegisterRequestInterface}>()
)
```

Here, I am just a little bit confused, how exactly is the action getting the correct props? I mean there is the `RegisterRequestInterface`, but that interface has a "`user`" property, so shouldn't it be `{request: RegisterRequestInterface["user"]}` ? But it seems to work nonetheless, how does this work inherently? Does it do an implicit type property match for a names object like "`user`"?
Also, if I add some other property inside RegisterRequestInterface like
`{ emailSubmitted: boolean}`, it doesn't complain that there is no field named like the property if submitting the form... and it still works, why?

EDIT: Added component form and code

```
<div class="auth-page">
    <div class="container page">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-xs-12">
                <h1 class="text-xs-center"> Sign up</h1>
                <p class="text-xs-center">
                    <a [routerLink]='["/login"]'>Have an account?</a>
                </p>
                <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                    <fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg " placeholder="Username " formControlName="username" />
                            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg " placeholder="Email " formControlName="email" />
                            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg " placeholder="Password " formControlName="password" />
                        </fieldset>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-xs-right " type="submit " [disabled]="isSubmitting$ | async">
                          Sign up 
                        </button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { select, Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { registerAction } from "../../store/actions";
import { isSubmittingSelector } from "../../store/selectors";

@Component({
  selector: 'mc-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.components.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  isSubmitting$: Observable<boolean>

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private store: Store) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initializeForm();
    this.initializeValues();
  }

  initializeForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      email:  ['', Validators.required, Validators.email],
      password:  ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  initializeValues():void {
    this.isSubmitting$ = this.store.pipe(select(isSubmittingSelector));
    console.log(this.isSubmitting$);
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log(this.form.value, this.form.valid);
    this.store.dispatch(registerAction(this.form.value));
  }

}
```

Comment: In Angular 13 and older there's no option to type the forms. So its value is always of type  `any`.  So that's the probable cause of it not complaining.  Could you please add the code of the component with the form to check if the interface is just working by chance?

Comment: In your post there is no code with the implementation of the "form" you mention, so it is impossible to find out how it's working. If I had to guess, your code is actually completely fine and you're not noticing something in it. In ngrx itself, there is no magic like "implicit property match for objects named `'user'`" or anything like that.

Comment: hm but in the component.ts I use `registerAction(this.form.value)` which has just the 3 properties from the form fields... If I specify anything else for the registerAction props interface like additional types or so, shouldn't it complain?